# Devide list from database into multiple section (React)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object, variables

I am currently struggling with this problem. Hopefully, you can help me :)

Data is selected from a Database and it returns Objects structured like this:

```
object = {
  id: 4,
  name: "Banana",
  idParent: 1 
}
```

idParent would be the section of the product.

There are a lot of products and a lot of sections so a simple

```
const sectionOne = [];

ObjectList.map(e => {
  if(e.idParent === 1) {
    sectionOne.push(e);
  }
})
```

would probably be wrong, because it should be possible to add other idParents in the future and code should not need some rework in that case.

Let's say there are 30 Objects, 10 have idParent = 1, 15 have idParent = 2 and the last 5 have idParent = 3.

How can the whole list be divided into these sections without making a variable for each section?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you need here is a `map` which groups the values of the list by `idParent`.

Example:

```js
const objectList = [{
  id: 4,
  name: "Banana",
  idParent: 1
},
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "apple",
    idParent: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "orange",
    idParent: 2
  }];

const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  return array.reduce((accumlator, value) => {
    (accumlator[value[key]] = accumlator[value[key]] || []).push(value);
    return accumlator;
  }, new Map());
};

const resultMap = groupBy(objectList, "idParent");

console.log(resultMap);
enter code here
```

The sub-arrays from the map can be access also like this:

```
const groupWihtIdParen1 = resultMap[1];
// or like this
const groupWithIdParent2 = resultMap.get(2);
``
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) If I try to run the snippet, it fails unfortunately :/

Comment: I am sorry, I your code works fine, I am just messy :3 Thank you very much